# Energy usage when attacking and closing attacks?

Tags: strategy, cycling, tour-de-france

In [Stage 11](https://youtu.be/J2DUD1Hsf9g?t=135) of the 2022 Tour de France, Vingegaard and Roglic used a double-attacking strategy against Pogacar. For example, Vingegaard attacks, Pogacar closes the attack, and Roglic drafts on Pogacar. Then Roglic attacks, Pogacar closes, and Vingegaard drafts.

How much energy is used by the three riders in one round of attacks? Is it: Vingegaard and Roglic each spend 1 unit when attacking, and Pogacar spends 2 units when closing? Or is it more like 1.5 units for Vingegaard and Roglic, since drafting uses up 0.5 units?